# Responsive navigation with "show more" that shows overflowed hidden buttons

Tags: html, css, frontend

Hi I'm implementing a navigation header composed of:

- 5 buttons, with some actions to perform
- A "Show More" button that shows overflowed hidden buttons when there is not enough space in a row.

Basically this is the front-end behavior i want to achieve:

[image]

When the width is reduced, the elements shown decrease due to available space:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions to help me do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you.